# Compare string elements of an array to object elements property of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, title says most of it, and I'll give an example:

```
var foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var bar = [
        {   
            integer: 1,
            string: 'one'
        },
        {   
            integer: 3,
            string: 'three'
        }       
    ];
```

Now, I'm wondering how can I get the list of positive matches for each of the elements in `foo` against each of the `string` properties of all the objects in array `bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make a set of all elements in `foo` to avoid square complexity:

```
var fooSet = {};    
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    var e = foo[i];
    fooSet[e] = true;
}
```

Then, go through `bar` and gather matches:

```
var matches = [];
for(var i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
    var e = bar[i];
    if(fooSet[e.string]) {
           matches.push(e);
    }
}
```

After this, `matches` array will contain the elements from `bar` that match the elements of `foo`.

Here's a live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/mfAc4/

Comment: +1. Creating `fooSet` makes this better than my answer that used `.indexOf()` (especially now that you've removed the for..in loops).

Comment: True, but this works only if foo and bar lengths are equal, which is not in my usecase. That's why I gave such an example. http://jsfiddle.net/mfAc4/

Comment: It works fine for different lengths of `foo` and `bar` - here's an example where `foo` has 8 and `bar` has 3 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mfAc4/1/ and here's an example where `foo` has 2 and `bar` has 3 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mfAc4/2/. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through one of the arrays checking each item against the other:

```
var matches = [],
    i, j;

for (i=0; i < bar.length; i++)
    if (-1 != (j = foo.indexOf(bar[i].string)))
       matches.push(foo[j]);

// matches is ['one', 'three']
```

Obviously if you want `matches` to contain the items from `bar` rather than `foo` just change the `.push()` statement to `matches.push(bar[i]);`.

Of course the above assumes you don't care about supporting older browsers that don't do `.indexOf()` on arrays, or that you can use [a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
// foo & bar defined here

// put all the keys from the foo array to match on in a dictionary (object)
var matchSet = {};
for (var item in foo)
{
    var val = foo[item];
    matchSet[val] = 1;
}

// loop through the items in the bar array and see if the string prop is in the matchSet
// if so, add it to the matches array
var matches = [];
for (var i=0; i < bar.length; i++)
{
    var item = bar[i];
    if (matchSet.hasOwnProperty(item['string']))
    {
        matches.push(item['string']);
    }
}

// output the matches (using node to output to console)
for (var i in matches)
{
    console.log(matches[i]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
match: one
match: three
```

NOTE: using node to run interactively

Answer (score 0):

These 2 work. Depends on how you want to use the data you can modify.

http://jsfiddle.net/KxgQW/5/

WAY ONE

```
//wasn't sure which one you want to utilize so I'm doing both
//storing the index of foo to refer to the array
var wayOneArrayFOO= Array();
//storing the index of bar to refer to the array
var wayOneArrayBAR= Array();

var fooLength = foo.length;
var barLength = bar.length;


/*THE MAGIC*/                
//loop through foo
for(i=0;i<fooLength;i++){

    //while your looping through foo loop through bar        
    for(j=0;j<barLength;j++){
        if(foo[i]==bar[j].string){
            wayOneArrayFOO.push(i);
            wayOneArrayBAR.push(j);    
        }
    }

}
```

WAY TWO

```
//storing the value of foo
var wayTwoArrayFOO= Array();
//storing the value of bar
var wayTwoArrayBAR= Array();            


/*THE MAGIC*/      
//loop through foo
for(i=0;i<fooLength;i++){

    //while your looping through foo loop through bar        
    for(j=0;j<barLength;j++){
        if(foo[i]==bar[j].string){
            wayTwoArrayFOO.push(foo[i]);
            wayTwoArrayBAR.push(bar[j]);    
        }
    }

}
```